# How to make twisted strips

Tags: mesh, materials

[image]

How can I make the twisted red and white strips on the cylinder? I have taken the cylinder and loop cut but how to twist the cylinder and get that spiral selection.

Comment: Why bother with twisted selection. Use a texture.

Comment: i don't need texture to be added. We i got the answer below hope it help u also

Comment: @atek - I agree with Mzidare. Using a texture (a 2d image of diagonal red and white stripes) wrapped around the cylinder allows you to keep the cylinder geometry simple, which should produce smoother and faster renders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a **circle** and go into edit mode. I adjusted the number of vertices to 16.
[image: circle 16 vertices]

In the Properties Panel, add a **Screw Modifier** to the object. Set the axis to Z and raise the Screw property until the proportions are correct.
[image: screw modifier]
Apply the modifier if you wish.
[image]

In face selection mode, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+rightclick on the face loops and assign them a new material.
[image]